# How to solve setState is always one step behind on React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am a beginner. I am learning react js. I am having an problem. `setState` is always one step behind.

Here is a sample:

[image]

Here, when I typed `i` then the console is showing nothing. Next, when I typed the `m` it shows `i` and as it is one step behind.

I have created two functions named `handleChange` and `handleKeyword`. The functions are behaving the same. I searched on the internet and got `useEffect()` suggestion to solve the problem but that has not solved my problem or I can't properly implement it.

Here is my codes:

**Home.jsx**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Search from '../../components/searchBar/Search';
import './home.scss';

const Home = () => {
  const [search, setSearch] = useState('');
  const [keyword, setKeyword] = useState('');

  const handleChange = event => {
    setSearch(event.target.value);
    console.log('Search: ', search);
  };

  const handleKeyword = () => {
    setKeyword(search);
    console.log('Keyword:', keyword);
  };

  return (
    <div className="container pb-5">
      <Search
        handleChange={handleChange}
        handleKeyword={handleKeyword}
        keyword={keyword}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

**Search.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import './search.scss'

const Search = props => {
  return (
    <div className="d-flex input-group justify-content-center">
      <input
        type="text"
        className="form-control searchBox"
        placeholder="Search for copyright free images & videos..."
        value={props.value}
        onChange={event => props.handleChange(event)}
      />
      <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={() => props.handleKeyword()}>
        Search
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Search;
```

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: `onChange` will always be behind. Use `onKeyDown` instead?

Comment: @evolutionxbox — That's not the problem. It's reading the value of `search` before the `onChange` callback has finished allowed the re-render to occur and generate a new value for `search` and a new `onChange` callback that has closed over the new value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **Home.jsx**, you can move the console statments inside `useEffect` with states search and keyword as dependencies to get the updated values. This issue is because react is declarative in nature so it decides when to setState runs. It can even be batched together for performance optimisations. So `useEffect` can be used in such cases to listen to change in states.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Search from '../../components/searchBar/Search';
import './home.scss';

const Home = () => {
  const [search, setSearch] = useState('');
  const [keyword, setKeyword] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
     console.log('Search: ', search);
     console.log('Keyword:', keyword);
   }, [search, keyword])

  const handleChange = event => {
    setSearch(event.target.value);
   };

  const handleKeyword = () => {
    setKeyword(search);
   };

  return (
    <div className="container pb-5">
      <Search
        handleChange={handleChange}
        handleKeyword={handleKeyword}
        keyword={keyword}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Comment: Actually, my target is not getting the search and keyword value immediately on the console. I want to set the value on search and keyword immediately.

Comment: You can pass `search` as a prop to  `<Search />` component.  And then inside Search component, ``` <input
        type="text"
        className="form-control searchBox"
        placeholder="Search for copyright free images & videos..."
        value={props.search}
        onChange={event => props.handleChange(event)}
      />
      <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={() => props.handleKeyword(props.search)}>
        Search
      </button>```
Also change `const handleKeyword = (val) => {setKeyword(val);};`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is setState just promise you that value will be updated It does not affect your code, just move console.logs outside handleClicks

So, when you set a new state and you will see a new value only **after rerender component**.

```
  const handleKeyword = () => {
    setKeyword(search);
    console.log("Keyword:", keyword);
  };

  console.log("Keyword:2", keyword);
```

`console.log("Keyword:", keyword);` will be called in the first render with the old value
`console.log("Keyword:2", keyword);` will be called in the second render with a new value.

Answer (score -1):

setState is async so changes to the state are not applied immediately.
see here https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

[image]

Comment: This isn't the reason for the delayed state update. The state isn't "late", it's a whole step behind

Comment: ...well, @evolutionxbox, I guess that kinda Is the  reason ... consider : rewrite of state update: `  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setSearch((prev) => {
      const newVal = event.target.value;
      console.log("Search: ", search);
      return newVal;
    });
  }; ` ... ie, setState is truly async, where next line console.log (in the original code) would be executed before `setState` would really set the new state (on event loop) ...